# How can I sort the results of a for each loop?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a list of strings `var_dump($key)`:

```
string(6) "samuel"
string(4) "john"
string(4) "alan"
string(5) "frank"
string(3) "bob"
```

They are a result of a loop from a multidimensional array:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) { 
   if(is_array($item)){
      if (stripos($key, $keySearch) !== false){
      var_dump($key);
      }
   }
}
```

Is it possible to sort this list of strings?

I tried:

```
   foreach ($array as $key => $item) {  
       if(is_array($item)){
          if (stripos($key, $keySearch) !== false){
          asort($key);
          var_dump($key);
          }
       }
    }
```

and also

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {  
       if(is_array($item)){
          if (stripos($key, $keySearch) !== false){
              array_multisort($key);
              var_dump($key);
          }
       }
    }
```

My sort attemts are not working. The problem is I cannot sort the `array` because it is a complex multidimensional array. So I somehow only want to sort the results. But I am not sure how to do that.

The result I wish for `var_dump($key)` would be:

```
string(4) "alan"
string(3) "bob"
string(5) "frank"
string(4) "john"
string(6) "samuel"
```

Comment: Show your attempt for multisort

Comment: Can you please show your actual array without `var_dump`?

Comment: @Thamilan You mean `echo $key`?

Comment: @Thamilan Then it is `samuel john alan frank bob`

Comment: @Jarla, You can't sort the key cause it is a single value not array. can you please give the `$array`.

Comment: @FrayneKonok Yes I found out, this was not the right way to go

Comment: @Jarla, Did you found the answer of it?

Comment: @FrayneKonok I didn't go on working with this way, because it is not a good way, I will close this question

Comment: okey, this is best decision

Answer (score 0):

PHP - Sort Functions For Arrays

```
sort() - sort arrays in ascending order
rsort() - sort arrays in descending order
asort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the value
ksort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the key
arsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the value
krsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the key
```

Comment: I tested all variations, but always get the same result. Cannot figure out the problem